# AWS RDS very long response time for remote requests

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We have the same website hosted on both:

- AWS EC2 instance
- Non-aws hosting

Both sites access data from AWS RDS database.

The site hosted on AWS loads pages with DB data instantly, whereas the site hosted on non-aws hosting loads pages with DB data in 60-90 seconds.

When DB copied from AWS RDS to the same non-aws hosting, site pages loads instantly.

So it looks like the problem is in accessing AWS RDS from outside aws (remote) locations.

Is there a way to get data from RDS remotely in a fast way, and how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of factors to evaluate here:

- Do you have inbound access to the RDS instance (via the security group), your application might look like its loading if the content served on the page is static so it might be a timeout.
- Similar to my first point is the RDS instance connectable, check that it either has a publicly connectable endpoint or that you have a VPN/Direct Connect to connect to the instance from your web host if its private.
- Which region is the instance in? It should be closer to where your host is to avoid network transit between your host and the database for each query. (Check out [CloudPing](https://www.cloudping.co/grid)). Remember that each query would have this latency per query.
- Are the resources like for like (CPU, memory and disk). If you have less resources available to the DB in AWS it's likely to take longer when complex queries are being used.